# how can i add the input to the link in the action for a sech bar?

Tags: html, django

I am currently writing some script in HTML that creates a search bar. The page seems to redirect to https://schedule.nylas.com/?, but I want it to redirect to the input in the search box.

i.e the input in the search box is icecreamshop and it goes to https://schedule.nylas.com/icecreamshop

```
 <form autocomplete="off" action="https://schedule.nylas.com" + input>
   <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
     <input id="myInput" type="text" name="" placeholder="store">
   </div>
   <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using javascript. If you just use the `onclick` attribute on the button then you don't even need to put it in a form. This just send the user to 'https://schedule.nylas.com/' + (input with id="myInput") when they click on the button.

```html
<input id="myInput" placeholder="Search">
<button onclick="window.location.href='https://schedule.nylas.com/'+document.getElementById('myInput').value;">Search</button>
```